# How can i list a user's groups when their names contain spaces?

Tags: linux, users, group, active-directory

Our site uses Active Directory, and many group names contain spaces. This renders the output of `groups` impossible to parse reliably, even by eye (are there groups "London" and "Developers", or a group "London Developers"?).

I can't see a way to get `groups` to either use another separator (line breaks or NULs would do), or to list groups by GID.

Is there a way to reliably get a list of a user's groups when some group names contain spaces?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3, and will happily install more packages, or write scripts!

Comment: Does the `id` command work for AD users? if so, that should have a `-z` option for null-delimiting the entries e.g. `id -Gnz`

Comment: @steeldriver both `id(1)` and `groups(1)` use the same interfaces (`getgrgid(3)`), so if `groups(1)` returns the right info, then `id -Gnz | tr '\0' '\n'` should do.

Comment: @steeldriver That works! Would you like to make that an answer, so i can accept it?

Comment: @TomAnderson thanks for confirming - answer posted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `groups` doesn't appear to have an option to null-delimit entries, `id` does - at least in the GNU CoreUtils implementation that should apply on Ubuntu 18.04<sup>1</sup>

```
   -z, --zero
          delimit entries with NUL characters, not whitespace;
```

So for example

```
id -Gnz someuser
```

should give a null-delimited list of the names of `someuser`'s supplementary groups - you can check that's the case using

```
id -Gnz someuser | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
```

<sup>1</sup> Note that POSIX doesn't mandate this option, so it won't be portable. See for example [The Open Group Base Specifications](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html)

Comment: @mosvy perhaps that should be an answer?

Answer (score 1):

On a system without GNU coreutils, you can do the same in perl with

```
perl -le 'print((getgrgid $_)[0]) for split " ", $)'
```

And similarly in any language which offers bindings to the `getegid(2)`, `getgroups(2)` and `getgrgid(3)` standard interfaces.

Notice that `getgroups(2)` may or may not return the effective gid of the process in the list -- this is something that the `$)` variable in perl and utilities like `groups` or `id` take care of (perl will prepend the real/effective gid to `$(`/`$)`, but will not remove it from the list returned by `getgroups(2)`).

Answer (score 1):

On a system with neither coreutils nor perl, but where at least the AD admins use sane group names that contain neither commas nor parentheses, one can parse the output of `id`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

list_of_groups="$(id | sed 's/^.* groups=//')"
one_group=

while [[ "$list_of_groups" != "$one_group" ]]
do {
        one_group="${list_of_groups%%,*}"
        list_of_groups="${list_of_groups#*),}"
        echo $one_group
} done |
sed -e 's/^[0-9]*(//' -e 's/)$//'
```